# Variable inputs for global command

Tags: macros, loops, package-writing, xparse

I'm developing a template and I have a janky but working way of making the approvals page:

I define various macros in the main document and then call a command from my package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\newcommand{\advisor}{Name, Degrees}

%uncomment the following line to add a second advisor
%\newcommand{\advisortwo}{Name, Degrees}

\newcommand{\dean}{Name, Degrees}
\newcommand{\reviewerone}{Name, Degrees}
\newcommand{\reviewertwo}{Name, Degrees}
\newcommand{\reviewerthree}{Name, Degrees}
\newcommand{\reviewerfour}{}
\newcommand{\reviewerfive}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\makeapprovals

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

Content

\end{document}
```

In my package, I have the following:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2017/03/21 Package info]


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\newcommand{\makeapprovals}[1]{\gdef\@\makeapprovals{#1}%
\chapter{Approvals}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\vspace*{1in}

Approval blurb.

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} 

\ifdefined\advisortwo
  \begin{tabular}{p{4in}p{1.5in}}
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    Dissertation Advisor - \advisor & Date \\ [10pt]
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    Dissertation Advisor - \advisortwo & Date \\ [10pt]
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    Dean - \dean & Date \\ 
\end{tabular}
\else
  \begin{tabular}{p{4in}p{1.5in}}
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    Dissertation Advisor - \advisor & Date \\ [10pt]
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    Dean - \dean & Date \\ 
\end{tabular}
\fi
\vskip 0.25in
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}
\textbf{\reviewerone}\\
\textbf{\reviewertwo}\\
\textbf{\reviewerthree}\\
\textbf{\reviewerfour}\\
\textbf{\reviewerfive}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

\endinput
```

I want to be able to define things this way and use loops:

```
\dean{Name, Degrees}
\advisor{Name, Degrees; Name, Degrees}
\reviewers{Name, Degrees; Name, Degrees; Name, Degrees}
\makeapprovals
```

I am aware that `xparse` allows such things, but I can't figure it out. Other syntaxes are fine if there's an easy way of doing things.

Comment: does it have to be that syntax, you can do that but a `;` is hard to spot when reading the file, I think `\advisor{Name, Degrees}\advisor{Name, Degrees}` is clearer?

Comment: How would that pass in a list of multiple advisors to the `\makeapprovals` function?

Comment: You don't really need a list as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `\singlespacing` for the bulk of the approvals page, because it makes it easier to control the spaces.

The advantage of the following approach is that the list of advisors and reviewers is available also for other purposes: the code for decorating the names is only added at the moment of building the approvals page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%% code to go in the package
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeapprovals}{}
 {
  \chapter*{Approvals}
  \thispagestyle{plain}

  Approval ~ blurb.

  \begin{center}
  \singlespacing
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4in}p{1.5in}@{}}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \g_bfh_template_advisors_seq }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__bfh_template_temp_tl
     {
      \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\
      Dissertation ~ Advisor ~ -- ~ \seq_item:Nn \g_bfh_template_advisors_seq { ##1 } & 
      Date \\[15pt]
     }
   }
   \tl_use:N \l__bfh_template_temp_tl
   \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\
   Dean ~ -- ~ \tl_use:N \g_bfh_template_dean_tl & Date \\
   \end{tabular}
   \par
   \vspace{0.25in}
   \bfseries
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
   \seq_use:Nn \g_bfh_template_reviewers_seq { \\ }
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\dean}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_bfh_template_dean_tl { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\advisors}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_bfh_template_advisors_seq { ; } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\reviewers}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_bfh_template_reviewers_seq { ; } { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \g_bfh_template_dean_tl
\tl_new:N \l__bfh_template_temp_tl
\seq_new:N \g_bfh_template_advisors_seq
\seq_new:N \g_bfh_template_reviewers_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
%% end of code for package

\begin{document}

\dean{Dean Name, Degrees}
\advisors{
  Advisor1 Name, Degrees;
  Advisor2 Name, Degrees;
  Advisor3 Name, Degrees;
  Advisor4 Name, Degrees
}
\reviewers{
  Reviewer1 Name, Degrees;
  Reviewer2 Name, Degrees;
  Reviewer3 Name, Degrees
}

\makeapprovals

\frontmatter

\makeapprovals

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

Content

\end{document}
```

[image]

For instance, you can define a macro `\advisedby` like

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\advisedby}{}
 {
  Advised ~ by ~ \seq_use:Nnnn \g_bfh_template_advisors_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
 }
```

(between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`, of course), which will do the right thing with one, two, three or more advisors:

- One advisor: “Advised by Advisor Name”
- Two advisors: “Advised by Advisor1 Name and Advisor2 Name”
- Three advisors: “Advised by Advisor1 Name, Advisor2 Name, and Advisor3 Name”

You can remove the Oxford comma, of course, from the trailing argument.

Comment: That is really good, and just what I need. I've been working (since I posted the question) on a similar solution with `etoolbox` which I will also post. The advantage of our solutions is that I can then do this: `Advised by \StrSubstitute{\advisor}{;}{ and}` and it will work.

Comment: @BFH I'll add a way to reuse the list of advisors.

Comment: That's certainly more robust than my way!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\addtolength\textwidth{62pt}
\makeatletter
\def\@advisor{}
\def\@reviewer{}
\def\@dean{}
\def\advisor#1{\g@addto@macro\@advisor{%
    Dissertation Advisor -- #1& Date \\[10pt]
    \hrulefill & \hrulefill \\%[-10pt] % really?
    }}
\def\reviewer#1{\g@addto@macro\@reviewer{#1\\}}
\def\dean#1{\g@addto@macro\@dean{\\#1}}

\def\makeapprovals{%
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{4in}p{1.5in}}\@advisor\\[10pt]\@dean\end{tabular}
\bigskip
 \begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}\@reviewer\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\makeatletter

\advisor{Advisor1, D1}
\advisor{Advisor2, D2}

\reviewer{Reviewer1, RD1}
\reviewer{Reviewer2, RD2}
\reviewer{Reviewer3, RD3}


\dean{Name, Degrees}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\makeapprovals

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

Content

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

% \applyto{..loop body..}{..list of items..}
\newcommand\applyto[2]{\def\doxloop{#1}\expandafter\xloop#2\relax}
\newcommand\xloop[1]{\ifx\relax#1\else\doxloop{#1}\expandafter\xloop\fi}

% \thedean, \theadvisors, and \thereviewers store the names provided
% repeatedly with \dean, \advisor, and \reviewer, respectively.
\newcommand\thedean{}
\newcommand\dean[1]{\def\thedean{#1}}
\newcommand\theadvisors{}
\newcommand\thereviewers{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\advisor[1]{\g@addto@macro\theadvisors{{#1}}}
\newcommand\reviewer[1]{\g@addto@macro\thereviewers{{#1}}}
\makeatother

% \dosignature{..function..}{..name..}
\newcommand\dosignature[2]%
  {\vspace*{15pt}\par\noindent
   \makebox[3in]{\hrulefill}\quad\makebox[1in]{\hrulefill}\\[-3pt]
   \parbox[t]{3in}{#1~-- #2}\quad\makebox[1in]{Date}%
   \par
  }

% \doreviewer{..name..}
\newcommand\doreviewer[1]%
  {\vspace*{15pt}\par\noindent
   \textbf{#1}%
   \par
  }

\newcommand\makeapprovals
  {\chapter*{Approvals}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \vspace*{1in}
   Approval blurb.
   \begin{center}
     \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
       \applyto{\dosignature{Dissertation Advisor}}\theadvisors
       \dosignature{Dean}\thedean
       \vskip 0.25in
       \applyto\doreviewer\thereviewers
     \end{minipage}
   \end{center}
  }

\begin{document}
\dean{DeanName, DeanDegrees}
\advisor{A1Name, A1Degrees}
\advisor{A2Name, A2Degrees}
\reviewer{R1Name, R1Degrees}
\reviewer{R2Name, R2Degrees}
\reviewer{R3Name, R3Degrees}
\makeapprovals
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is amazing. How do I access a specific definition of each macro elsewhere and count the number of times defined?

Comment: `\edef\theadvisors{` beware edef if any advisors have accented letters in their name this will blow up. You could use protected@edef (or g@addto@macro as in mine:-)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused. `edef` seems to be what you used to make an expanded list. What I want to do is access a specific item from that list so that I can, for instance display the names again as "A1Name, A1Degrees and A2Name, A2Degrees" instead of "A1Name, A1DegreesA2Name, A2Degrees" If I do a regular loop, it would show up as "A1Name, A1Degrees and A2Name, A2Degrees and" instead.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the advice, I have improved the answer.

Comment: @BFH The best solution depends on your use case; this may not be access via numbers, though this is of course possible. If you just want to insert "and": `\newcommand\inter{\def\inter{ and }}\applyto\inter\theadvisors`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution using `etoolbox`. Like egreg's solution, it ends up with usable strings afterwards.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin = 1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\dean[1]{\def\dean{#1}}
\newcommand\advisor[1]{\def\advisor{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewers[1]{\def\reviewers{#1}}

\newcommand{\makesigline}[1]{%
\hrulefill & \hrulefill \\[-10pt]
    #1 & Date \\ [10pt]}

\DeclareListParser*\forsemicolonlist{;}
\newcommand\handler[1]{%
\makesigline{Dissertation Advisor - #1}}
\newcommand\secondhandler[1]{\textbf{#1}\\}

\newcommand{\makeapprovals}[1]{\gdef\@\makeapprovals{#1}%
\chapter*{Approvals}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\vspace*{1in}

Approval blurb.

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} 

\begin{tabular}{p{4in}p{1.5in}}
    \expandafter\forsemicolonlist\expandafter\handler\expandafter{\advisor}
    \makesigline{Dean - \dean} 
\end{tabular}
\vskip 0.25in
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}
\expandafter\forsemicolonlist\expandafter\secondhandler\expandafter{\reviewers}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

\advisor{Foo, Degrees; Bar, Degrees}
\dean{Name, Degrees}
\reviewers{Foobar, Degrees; Barbar, Degrees; Bazbar, Degrees}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\makeapprovals

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}

Advised by \StrSubstitute{\advisor}{;}{ and}


\end{document}
```

[image: First page with approvals]

[image: Lists are still accessible]